# ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed (python3.4)?

Tags: python3

l stuck with  this error
please help

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by changing the backend to `TkAgg`. Simply go to your `.matplotlibrc` file and change the backend.

Usually the file is saved in home directory: `~/.matplotlibrc`

If it is not there, you can try to look into:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
```

Here you need to replace the python version 3.4 by yours.